# What can GNS3 and Packet Tracer be used for besides simulations?

Tags: networking, scripting, network-programming, ip, cisco

I am new to GNS3 and Cisco's Packet Tracer. Besides using GNS3 to simulate complex networks, practice using it for the CCNA exam, and using Dynamips emulation software to simulate Cisco IOS, how is it used in the real world by big companies and corporations?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can also be used for documentation of the networks topology,Top Level Structure, IP address distribution and much more.

Answer (score 1):

It' used for testing complex network configuration like firewall rules or SDN configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to train on the firewall and servers and connect it to vmware, and also create large projects on the GNS3 and put it in the CV if you haven't experience

Answer (score 0):

It can also be used to test how a network will behave by installing actual Operating system images and a sniffer. Basically it can be used to mimic the actual scenario with the proper resources.